# Least cost path from multiple sources to multiple destinations across resistance layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, cost-surface

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.7. I have little experience with ArcPy so using geoprocessing tools would be preferable. I would like to determine the number of boats that could potentially visit coastal islands.  I am using a warves point layer to represent the boat launch sites (starting points), and a coastal islands polygon shapefile as the destination islands. I have a wind exposure shapefile to be used as the surface cost with exposure ranked 1-4 (4 is highest cost) that covers the open water between the warves and the islands.  I would like to simulate boats departing from warves as a least cost path line but they can only travel across the surface cost 1 or 2 (avoiding cost 3 and 4) to reach the islands. Then I would like to sum the number of boats (lines) that reach each island from warves within a 10 km total travel distance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 3 and 4 from your surface, i.e. make them NODATA using raster calculator:
[image]
Compute cost distance and backlink raster to your islands and use departure points and 2 above rasters to Cost Path as Polyline tool:
[image]
You can delete lines exceeding length limit and find destination islands by using spatial join between remaining paths and island polygons.

Comment: I tried this approach however the final path as polyline output is empty. For the cost distance tool, do I use the warf points shapefile as the feature source data or the island polygons? And for the cost as polyline tool, do I use the islands or warf points as the destination data? And which "path type" from the drop down in the tool, should I be using?

Comment: Islands for backlinks, what's for paths, each cell. I'd sample distance raster to points to see if they are reachable at all. If not try excluding zone 4 only from cost surface.